# Can I use Html Agility Pack to load elements from current page?

Tags: html, ajax, html-agility-pack

I load a DIV content using from an html file using and display the content in .aspx page

```
DocHtml.Load(@"C:\EmailsMKT\modelo1\modelo1.html");
HtmlNode Nodes = DocHtml.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='emailMkt']");
```

them I display the content like this:

```
lblMail.Text = DocHtml.DocumentNode.OuterHtml
```

My question is how modify elements in this DIV using ajax(UpdatePanel) and them save into a different file.

Is that possible to load the html of the current page insted a file ?

Comment: What do you mean the current page?

Comment: I load the html from a file into inside DIV in the page Email.aspx, them I want to modify the some values in the HTML that a just load after pressing a button and show again de modifications, but without modify the file that you just loaded, and after all modifications save the modified DIV content into a different file.

Comment: I'm having the same problem...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413949/xpath-table-changes-as-combox-changes-too#comment15053710_11413949